# How to replace only default date with blank in date field of JQgrid

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net, jqgrid-formatter

I am using JQgrid and want to replace only default date to blank in date field of JQgrid.

please find code snippet for date field in JQGrid

```
     mtype: "GET"
     datatype: 'json',
     colModel: [
                {
                 name: 'Current_Linkage_Date', 
                 index:'Current_Linkage_Date', 
                 title: false, sorttype: "date",   formatter:'date',
                 formatoptions: { srcformat: 'Y-m-d H:i:s', newformat: 'd-M-Y',
                 defaultValue:null },
                    searchoptions: { sopt: ["eq", "lt", "le", "gt", "ge"] }
                         },
         ]
```

As back in controller I am getting null date as

```
 Current_Linkage_Date = row.Field<DateTime?>(13).GetValueOrDefault(),
```

Kindly help me to find how i can get blank value instead default date value.

Thanking in Advance.

Comment: Can you please show the response (or part of them)  from the server, which contain null date value? I think that the null data is not null, but something else.

Comment: yes, it is displaying as "01-Jan-2001" as default value

Comment: please show the response from the server - the JSON data that come from the server.

Answer (score 0):

The date type not support `defaultValue:null`, so it not works in your code.

**[Official Doc:](http://www.trirand.com/blog/phpjqgrid/doc/_2v70wa4jv.htm)**

*Below is a list of the predefined format types*

[image]